# How to modify an XSD schema to perform a specific xquery

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery

I need to modify an XSD schema so i can perform a particular XQuery looking for type name

I have tried to play around with namespaces but I could not get it right.

This is the XSD schema:

```
<xs:group name="Axiom" >
    <xs:choice >

        <xs:element ref="el-typed:equivalent"/>
        <xs:element ref="el-typed:subsumes"/>
        <xs:element ref="el-typed:instance-of"/>
        <xs:element ref="el-typed:related-to"/>
    </xs:choice>

</xs:group>

<xs:element name="equivalent">

    <xs:complexType>

        <xs:sequence >
            <xs:group  minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="el-typed:ClassExpression"/>
        </xs:sequence>

    </xs:complexType>

</xs:element>

<xs:element name="subsumes">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:group minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" ref="el-typed:ClassExpression"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="instance-of">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="el-typed:constant"/>
            <xs:group ref="el-typed:ClassExpression"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="related-to">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="el-typed:constant"/>
            <xs:element ref="el-typed:constant"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="prop" use="required" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And this is the XQuery:

```
(validate {doc("el1.xml")})//element(*,Axiom)
```

When used on well-formed XML valid against schema it should return all type Axioms which are the elements: `equivalent`, `subsumes`, `instance-of`, `related-to`.

Atat the moment Oxygen says this about the XQuery:

> Unknown type name
>   Q{http://www.cs.manchester.ac.uk/pgt/COMP60411/el}Axiom

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the type name "Axiom" unless it is declared in a schema referenced by an "import schema" declaration within the query, or some equivalent (vendor-defined) way of making the schema known to the query processor. The error message suggests to me that the schema hasn't been made known to the query processor, not that you need to modify the schema.

Furthermore: the error message referring to Q{http://www.cs.manchester.ac.uk/pgt/COMP60411/el}Axiom suggests that there must be a default namespace declared somewhere. You haven't shown us anything that declares that namespace; in fact it seems you have carefully trimmed out anything from the schema or query that declares namespaces. Since your question says that you suspect a namespace-related problem, this seems singularly unhelpful.